# Locality Sensitive Hashing for Sets

Tags: sets, hash, hashing, euclidean-distance

Are there locality sensitive hashes that work nicely with sets? Each set would get a hash, the order of the elements in the set does not change the hash, and sets that share more elements are closer together.

Specifically, I am working with sets that each have approximately 10 elements, and there are a total of 1000000 unique elements across all sets (so creating a vector to binary encode the presence/absence of each element in each set is prohibitive).

Any direction to an algorithm for this would be much appreciated. Thank you very much for any guidance or feedback.

Comment: (I've seen *locality* sensitive hash function, and assumed a relation to memory hierarchy, too.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  [MinHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash) is one example of a locality sensitive hash for sets.